# Rails Associations and Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to create a journal where a logged in user's `journal_entries` are listed when the index view is called.

I have installed the Devise gem for the user sign up, log in/out authentication.

I have created a model, `JournalEntries`, which includes a date, string and text fields.

After creating the database, `rake db:create` and then migrating, `rake db:migrate` - I attempted to list a users journal entries in the journal_entries/index view.  The default view that was derived via scaffolding lists ALL USERS journal_entries.  This doesn't make for a great journal - where you can see the entries of all other users.

In my research I've come to realize that I didn't have a field in the `journal_entries` table which referenced the users table.

I create a migration show below:

```
class AddForeignKeyToJournalEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :journal_entries do |t|
        t.references :user
    end
    #add a foreign key
    execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE journal_entries
            ADD CONSTRAINT fk_journal_entries_users
            FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
            REFERENCES users(id)
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
        ALTER TABLE journal_entries
            DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_journal_entries_users
    SQL
  end

end
```

(I also changed the users.rb and journal_entries.rb models to include belongs_to and has_many association - at first I thought this is all I had to do, and somehow the database would pick this up, but it didn't...)

This successfully added foreign key - user_id to the journal_entries table, and I thought I was in the clear.

What is happening now is when a journal_entry is created - the user_id column is blank - no info is being populated there....?  I have verified this by logging into Postgres on my local machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your model should be called `JournalEntry`, not `JournalEntries`. As for your blank `user_id` column... Why wouldn't it be blank? What are you assigning to it? There is no magic means by which the foreign key is populated, you need to place some value there yourself. We need to see that part of the code, so please add it to your question and remove the Github link. Your answer needs to be self-contained, it can't depend on external links to be meaningful.

Comment: Yes, sorry meagar, the model is called JournalEntry, the resulting table is called journal_entries.  That evidently is not the problem - but thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Meagar - I thought the user_id field would be populated with the id field from the :users table?  I know this is basic knowledge for you - but not for me.  I will leave the github link if that is all right with you, perhaps someone else has a little more patience.

Comment: It's not about patience; you *need* to include enough information in your question for your question to be answerable, or it will be closed. And no, the `user_id` field isn't set to anything automatically. How would Rails know what value to use? What if there are 10 users in he users table?

Comment: One last comment, meagar - why did you edit out the preface to my post here - saying that I was a newbie?  just curious...

Comment: Because it wasn't useful. Your posts should be as succinct as possible. Chitchat, salutations, introductions, signatures, taglines, these don't belong on Stack Overflow. We're stringing for *reference-quality* posts, not forum quality posts. The primary purpose for your question to exist is to help *future users* who have the same question. Those users may or may not be newbies, and they almost certainly won't be named "John".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason the user_id column is blank in the journal_entry table is because you need to add the current user's id when a new journal entry is created.

In your JournalEntries Controller you'll need to add this to your create action:

`@journal_entry.user_id = current_user.id`

or, `@journal_entry.user = current_user`

Then, in your JournalEntries Controller index action:

Instead of `@journal_entries = JournalEntry.all` you can display only the current logged in user's entries with `@journal_entries = current_user.journal_entries`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend that you read through the material for [Rails Guides Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to get a better understanding of how models are linked and how they interact.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that when you build a new instance of the `JournalEntry` that it has knowledge of the association with the current user:

```ruby
# app/controllers/journal_entries_controller.rb
...
def create
  @journal_entry = current_user.build_journal_entry(params[:journal_entry])
...
```

See the relevant part of the Rails Guide for [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-build_association).

Comment: Thanks, although I've read the Rails Guide, I wasn't getting a clear understanding until I saw both of the answers here!  Thank you for your time in explaining!